# Keeping a functor in a separate file

Tags: ocaml, functor

I have a functorized graph type

```
module type GRAPH_LABELS =
    sig
        type label
    end

module type GRAPH =
    sig
        type label
        type graph
        val init : int -> graph
        val size : graph -> int
        val insert_directed_edge : graph -> int -> int -> label -> unit
        val insert_edge : graph -> int -> int -> label -> unit
        val neighbours : graph -> int -> (int*label) list
    end

module Graph = functor (L : GRAPH_LABELS) ->
    struct
        (* implementation which matches GRAPH *)
    end
```

I'd like to keep it in a separate file. I put everything into `graph.ml`. When I create a module out of a functor

```
module VoidLabels = struct type label = unit end
module Gr = Graph (VoidLabels)
```

I get an error:

```
This module is not a functor; it has type
       sig
         module type GRAPH_LABELS = sig type label end
         module type GRAPH = (* ... *)
```

How should I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should have `module Gr = Graph.Graph (VoidLabels)`.

Comment: And how should I modify my source code to make my calls legal?

Comment: Add `open Graph` in the beginning of the file. You can't put a functor as a toplevel name, so there is no other way.